# phpmailer file_get_contents and dynamic php code

Tags: php, encoding, file-get-contents, phpmailer

ok im kind of going around in circles, what i want to do is simple. I have a web page which pulls information from an API into an object, iterates through various objects and displays the information in simple html tables.

Now this info displays as expected when i load the page. There is a lot of content in it.

What i want to do is setup a cron job to send a daily report via email based on this php page. With standard HTML it seems to work fine, when i use dynamic php code it seems to mess things up.

Originally i tried with standard php mail, this was just displaying the source code, someone suggested using file_get_contents with phpmailer and thats where im at now but im a little out of my depth. Is there some sort of escaping or encoding/decoding i should be doing, the whole idea was i wouldnt have to escape the code line by line so i hope not :(

Here is a snippet of the code im running:

```
<body>

<?php

$username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'xxx';

$url ='xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project+%3D+bug+AND+updated+%3C%3D+2d+AND+status+%3D+%22In+Beta%22+AND+assignee+!%3D+beta_merge+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$issue_list = curl_exec($curl);
$issue_json = json_decode($issue_list);
//var_dump($issue_json);
$bugs = $issue_json->issues;


?>
<h2>Table 1</h2>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="80%">
    <?php foreach ($bugs as $bug)
            {?>
                <tr>
<td><?php echo $bug->fields->issuetype->iconUrl; ?></td>
</tr>


            <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Now if i load the page i see:

Table 1

```
http://www.xxx.com/images/bug_16.png

http://www.xxx.com/images/bug_16.png

http://www.xxx.com/images/feature_16.png

http://www.xxx.com/images/bug_16.png
```

But if i run this:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('jira_filters.php');
//$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "xxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@gmail.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "xxx@him.net";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Then this is the output i see when the email arrives is:

```
issues; ?> 

Table 1

fields->issuetype->iconUrl; ?>
```

I just want the email to show exactly what i see in the browser when loading the page. Is there an easy way to do this, tried searching but finding it hard to describe what im looking to do as i dont know if its possible with phpmailer or if i need encoding etc?

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the file, just literally getting the file's contents and placing them as email body.

Try this instead:

```
ob_start();
include 'jira_filters.php'; //execute the file as php
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

The `ob_start()` makes every normal echo and direct html, text etc (stuff outside `<?php` tags) become buffered instead of being output somewhere. You then
get what it's in the buffer with `ob_get_clean()`, and send *that* as email.